# How can we distinguish "uptalk" from a real question?

Tags: speech, intonation

**uptalk** or **high rising terminals** is an intonation pattern where declarative statements occur with yes/no question intonation.

> "It is used when the speaker is establishing common ground with the listener as the basis for the conversation, and when the speaker is seeking silent affirmation or some factor that would otherwise require explanation before the conversation could continue."
>    - - (*J.K.Chambers, Language Myths, Penguin Books, 1998.*)

e.g. Our high-school class is doing an experiment on genetics?

> Uptalk has spread to virtually all English speaking countries in the world and its uses have spread to contexts where the pragmatics are not quite so clear:

e.g. "Hello, my name is Christopher?"

I've never come into contact with someone who uses that pattern of speech. For this reason I ask: is it possible to distinguish uptalk from a real question or is the intonation used identical?

Comment: I think the answer is: sometimes we *can't*. But it's such an irritating habit I'm sure people who do it are accustomed to being ignored anyway - so they shouldn't think it's odd if you fail to answer on the odd occasion when they're *really* asking a question.

Comment: My cousins from Eastern Pennsylvania have an odd habit of inserting uptalk into the middle of a question instead of at the end:  "Do you *like* David Bowie?"  "Are you *going* to the party?".  I have no idea where it came from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quantitative measurements of pitch excursion in stressed vowels among speakers with high rising terminals suggest that even in Southern California the excursions for declarative sentences are smaller in magnitude than those for questions or requests for confirmation. (Google: high rising terminal excursion).

In other words, distinguishing them is a matter of degree. For an unknown speaker with a very short fragment of speech it may not be possible, but in conversation I have personally never had an issue distinguishing these intonations after a short time adapting. It's not unique in that regard: the position of vowels in various dialects differs enormously, but is soon accommodated in extended conversation.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard the expression "uptalk" but I know what you are talking about. In this country (UK) we associate this manner of speaking with Americans, especially American females under the age of say 30. British people do not use it, unless they are trying to sound American. The intonation is exactly as in a question, but it is distinguishable from a question by the fact that no question is actually posed.

Comment: Take my first example (Our high school...) If someone said that to me I would most certainly understand it as a question. Then again, I'm not a college student and I don't live in an English speaking country. Chances are nobody would talk to me like that.

Comment: @fdb, re UK: It is rather rare in Great Britain, but not unknown, and common in parts of Northern Ireland it's common where it's called "Belfast upspeak" (and variations on that theme). As the OP knows, it's most often known formally as a High Rising Terminal, though in GB often called Australian Questioning Intonation and popularly associated with the popularity of Ozzie soaps in the 1980s. There are competing theories about its origin and spread in the UK, none widely supported.

Comment: @DanSheppard yes, it is certainly common here in Oz among the groups portrayed in those soaps.